# Why local state also changed when redux store updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Now I'm building an application using react redux store and local store.
I have two components "tweetTable_Comp" and "likeButton_Comp".
The redux store has all the tweets record "tweets" fetched by an API, and tweetTable_Comp has a local state "filteredTweets" so as to add filter function later and show only selected genre tweets.

And every tweet has likingUserIds.
tweetTable_Comp passes likingUserIds as props to likeButton_Comp so that it can add different style depending on if you already liked the tweet or not.

The problem here is that changing the "tweets[indexNum].likingUserIds" in the redux store when user push like button also affects on the local state "filteredTweets[indexNum].likingUserIds".

I was gonna change the redux info and local state info one by one like in deleteTweet function which already works well.
But this is not intentionally working.

Can anyone teach me why this is happening?

here is reducer.js
redux tweets has objects as below

・title(string)
・text(string)
・createdDate(string)
・likingUserIds(array)
・userId(number)

```
const defaultState = {
  user: {
    loggedIn: false,
    id: 0,
    account: ''
  },
  tweets: []
}

export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_TWEETS':
     return {
       ...state,
       tweets: action.tweets
     }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here is actions.js

```
export function getTweets(tweets){
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_TWEETS',
    tweets: tweets
  }
}
```

here is tweetTable_Comp

```
class TweetTable_Comp extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const {dispatch} = props;
    this.action = bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
    this.deleteButtonClicked = this.deleteButtonClicked.bind(this)
    this.editButtonClicked = this.editButtonClicked.bind(this)
    this.handleChanged = this.handleChanged.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      filteredTweets: [],
      searchWord: ""
    }
  }

  handleChanged(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  deleteButtonClicked(id, index){
    confirm("削除しますか？") &&
    this.deleteTweet(id, index)
  }

  editButtonClicked(id){
    this.props.history.push("/edit/" + id)
  }

  deleteTweet(id, index){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/twitter/deleteTweet/" + id, {
      method: "DELETE"
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.status === 200) {
        const newList = this.props.tweets.slice()
        newList.splice(index, 1)
        this.action.getTweets(newList)
        this.setState({filteredTweets: newList})
      }
    })
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/twitter/sendAllTweets", {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json()
      .then(json => {
        this.action.getTweets(json)
        this.setState({filteredTweets: json.slice()})
      })
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <h1 className="text-center">tweet一覧</h1>
        <SearchBar searchWord={this.state.searchWord} handleChanged={this.handleChanged}/>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                  <tr className="text-center">
                    <th>投稿日</th>
                    <th>投稿者</th>
                    <th>タイトル</th>
                    <th>内容</th>
                    <th>いいね</th>
                    <th>削除</th>
                    <th>編集</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  { this.state.filteredTweets.map((tweet, index) => (
                    <tr key={tweet.id}>
                      <td className="text-center">{tweet.createdDate}</td>
                      <td className="text-center">{tweet.user.account}</td>
                      <td>{tweet.title}</td>
                      <td>{tweet.text}</td>
                      <td className="text-center">
                        <LikeButton likingUserIds={tweet.likingUserIds} index={index} id={tweet.id} />
                      </td>
                      <td className="text-center">
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={() => this.deleteButtonClicked(tweet.id, index)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                      <td className="text-center">
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={() => this.editButtonClicked(tweet.id)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
                  }
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    )
  }
}

TweetTable_Comp.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  tweets: PropTypes.array,
  history: PropTypes.object,
  user:PropTypes.object
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return state
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(TweetTable_Comp))
```

here is likeButton_Comp

```
class LikeButton_Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const {dispatch} = props
    this.action = bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    this.likeButtonClicked = this.likeButtonClicked.bind(this)
  }

  likeButtonClicked(func, index){
    const data = {
      userId:this.props.user.id,
      tweetId:this.props.id
    }
    if(func === "unlike"){
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/twitter/like", {
        method: "DELETE",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then((response) => {
          if(response.status === 200){
            let tweets = this.props.tweets.slice()
            const orgLikingUsers = this.props.tweets[index].likingUserIds.slice()
            const newLikingUsers = orgLikingUsers.filter(item => item !== this.props.user.id)
            tweets[index].likingUserIds = newLikingUsers
            this.action.getTweets(tweets)
          } else {
            alert("処理に失敗しました")
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
      } else {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/twitter/like", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if(response.status === 200){
            let tweets = this.props.tweets.slice()
            let likingUsers = this.props.tweets[index].likingUserIds.slice()
            likingUsers.push(this.props.user.id)
            tweets[index].likingUserIds = likingUsers
            this.action.getTweets(tweets)
          } else {
            alert("処理に失敗しました")
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
      }
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <span>{this.props.likingUserIds.length}  </span>
      {this.props.tweets.length > 0 && this.props.likingUserIds.includes(this.props.user.id) ?
        <Button variant="outline-danger">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} onClick={() => this.likeButtonClicked("unlike", this.props.index)}/>
        </Button> :
        <Button variant="outline-secondary">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} onClick={() => this.likeButtonClicked("like", this.props.index)}/>
        </Button>
      }
      </>
    )
  }
}

LikeButton_Comp.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  user: PropTypes.object,
  tweets: PropTypes.array,
  likingUserIds: PropTypes.array,
  index: PropTypes.number,
  id: PropTypes.number
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return state
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(LikeButton_Comp))
```

Comment: Since you're mutating the tweet directly on this line:            `tweets[index].likingUserIds = newLikingUsers` the updated `likingUserIds` is reflected immediately in the other component.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
But I wonder why this reflects to the local state filteredTweets.
Because tweets mutated in that line is shallow copied at a few rows ahead by splice method.(let tweets = this.props.tweets.slice())
And seems like nothing to do with filteredTweets.

Comment: The key there is shallow filtered - the tweets array is a new array but each tweet in that array is not deep copied when taking a slice.

Comment: @azudo
Thank you!
I misunderstood what shallow copy means.A shallow copied object has the same address and when it refers the same data.That's why changes on one side reflects the another.

Comment: Yep, you got it!